# How to make parent boxes so that data is not visible untill clicked?(Treemap, plotly)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, treemap

```
fig = px.treemap(Data,
                path=[Year,AC_NAME,PARTY],
                values=Vote_Share,
                color=PARTY,title='Sales/Profit Overview',
                )
```

When I use this code I get something like this:
[image]

How do I make two-parent boxes like this :

[image]

Now when someone clicks on 2016 he gets 2016 stuff inside and when he clicks 2011 he gets 2011 data inside. I don't want it to be visible

Here is whole [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ei0dWvyh4CPqgBW5BS3mPnHt0A3GK6FC/view?usp=sharing)
and [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10Hq2APBJ1EfEcvayeNzGhLG8SM0N-eLK/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm not sure what behavior you want to achieve, but I think the path you need to set should have the following contents.`path=['State','YEAR','AC_NAME','PARTY'],` And you can specify the columns directly.

Comment: @r-beginners Ok let me try. I ll get back to uou

Comment: @r-beginners [here](https://prnt.sc/10u62ld) i get something like this.I don't want it like that.I want in the beginning 2 squares....One has 2011 and the other has 2016 written on it. When I click 2011 i should get all the data related to 2011, same with 2016

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `maxdepth` parameter in `px.Treemap()` to achieve this.

For example setting `maxdepth` = 1 in your example would produce the second figure, and then once you click on one of them, the partitioning would show up.

Hope this helps! Was trying to figure this out myself.